# UIScrollView vs TableView with UITextFields

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have multiple text fields that I'm placing in a scroll view right now which works fine. However, I've heard of people placing text fields in table views too, which got me thinking, is it better to place my text fields in a table view for performance reasons, or does it not matter that much considering only some of my text fields reuse the same style ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in that situation many times before and I prefer always using UIScrollView. Using tableView is very complex and you need to handle reusing of cells to set the text that was written in this field. For performance the both are fine except if you have many many fields and in that case the reusing will be helpful.

Also the problem in using UIScrollView, you have to handle opening keyboard to extend the content size of scrollView and animate it field above keyboard to be visible. 
For flexibility to change and customize everything, ScrollView is perfect

Comment: What is the best approach to do this in 2020? @Hossam

Answer (score 1):

If the number of textfields are low, then u should use scrollview as you will be knowing the number of them and you can maintain it better.

Only use tableview with textfields inside when either you dont know how many textfields you want and its a user depended or dynamic behaviour, or you have a fairly large amount of textfields. Managing them in tableview is also a headache.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on majorly 2 reasons:

**Are you reusing mostly the same type of textfields?**

If yes, then you can opt for `UITableView`, because you only need to set the properties on a single plac., and implementing changes is way easier, because you only have to make the changes at a single place.

If no, then move to question 2.

**2. Do you have more textfields than the superview's frame?**

If yes, then again you should opt for `UITableView`. You will need the reusability. In this case, even if you have 2-3 different types of textfields, you will still get better performance. And also, implementing changes is still easier.

If no, then you should go for `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, tableViews make your code scalable.

May be now you might be having low number of textfields.

But even if you want to make slight changes to your textfields in future, you have to revisit each and every textfield and make changes.

But in case of tableView, you will be using the custom cells which will be reused. So you have to change at one place, and even if you want to increase the number of textfields, you just have to increase the number of cells in table view. Whereas in scrollview, you again have to create the new ones.

Comment: can't we use stackView inside ScrollView, and then we can increase any time we want .?